# Контантенировать два массива?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите алгоритм. Есть массив из 10 элементов. И есть второй массив из n элементов. Нужно каждый раз когда приходит второй массив, заполнять первый и добавлять элементы вначало первого. Пришло 5 новых элементов, добавляем вначало и получаем 5 заполненных и 5 пустых в первом массиве. Доабвлять нужно до тех пор пока не станет 10 элементов в первом.

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: ну вот я создал массив из пустых объектов

  const teamsArray = new Array(10).fill(({
      id: '',
      name: ''
    }));

дальше у меня приходит другой массив, откуда добавляю элементы в этот пустой массив. Я делаю конкатенацию. но получаю соотвественно не вместо тех пустых эелементов. получаю 10 пустых +5 пришедших

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего использовать функцию `unshift` для добавления элемента в начало массива и "обрезать" массив через `slice`.

### Пример с `unshift` и `slice`

```js
let teamsArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
let teamsArrayNew = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

function updateArray(entryArray, newArray) {
  newArray = newArray.reverse();
  newArray.forEach(function(element) {
    entryArray.unshift(element);
    if (newArray.length <= 10) {
      entryArray = entryArray.slice(0, 10);
    } else {
      entryArray = entryArray.slice(0, newArray.length);
    }
  });
  return entryArray;
}

teamsArray = updateArray(teamsArray, teamsArrayNew);

console.log(teamsArray);
```

Функция `reverse` использовалась, потому что `forEach` делает обход с конца массива.

Comment: а если Один массив состоит из 10 пустых элементов, он предзаполнен фейковыми данными пустыми,второй максимум из 60 элементов. Пока есть места в первом массиве мы заполняем (перезаписываем)его пришедшими элементами из второго массива. Как места закончились, мы добавляем элементы в первых массив до 62

итого получим массив из 62 элементов

Comment: то есть ограничения нет

Comment: @werty в данном случае, если вы начнете добавлять к первому второй массив где 60 элементов, то в первом окажутся 10 последних элементов второго массива, если вам нужно, то можете изменить это число на то которое нужно. все как у вас в вопросе

Comment: у меня поулается так. сначала показываются 10 карточек (10 элеентов массива), прихоидт например массив с одним элементом. этот элемент встает на первое место и получаем 1 заполенный эелемент + 9 пустых. Дальше приходит например 2 элемента, получаем 2 заполненных + 8 пустых. Приходит 11 элементов, просто показываем 11 элементов

Comment: @werty хорошо, сейчас поправлю, просто в вопросе у вас об этом не написано

Comment: @werty смотри, сейчас работает как тебе нужно

Comment: да! все верно! спасибо!
еще бы проверку добавить что совпадают ли данные пришедшего массива с тем что есть сейчас. если да,то ничего не делаем

Comment: то есть элементы пришедшего массива совпадают ли с теми,что у нас есть. если ничего не изменилось то оставляем старый

Comment: @werty да, вы же будите 'обновлять' массив перед каждым вызовом, если пришло, то что было до этого, то массив будет содержать те же значения, что и до этого

Comment: имею в виду. может стоить сначала сравнить два массива . если пришедший . инаш содержат одни и те же данные, то не делать манипуляций с unshift и reverse ?

Comment: @werty смотрите сами, можете проверку дополнительную написать, но если оставить все как есть, то массив просто перезапишется и будет тоже что и было до этого

Answer (score 1):

В общем виде Вашу задачу можно решить так (у Вас второй массив, очевидно, приходит извне; у меня здесь для наглядности он создаётся рандомной длины по нажатию на кнопку, но суть та же самая):

```js
let mainArr = new Array(10); // создаём пустой массив длиной 10 элементов

function concat(mainArr, newArr) { // создаём функцию объединения
  for(let i = 0; i <= newArr.length-1; i++) { // в цикле проверяем
    if(mainArr[mainArr.length-1] == undefined) { // если последний элемент массива пустой
      mainArr.unshift(newArr[i]); // заполняем массив с первого элемента
      mainArr.pop(); // а последний удаляем
    }
    else { // если не пустой
      console.log('Массив заполнен!'); // сообщаем об этом
      break; // и прерываем цикл
    }
  }
}

// функция для получения рандомного числа
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() { // по клику на кнопку
  let random = getRandomInt(1,6); // получаем рандомное число
  let newArr = new Array(random); // создаем второй массив
  for(let i = 0; i <= newArr.length-1; i++) {
    newArr.splice(i, 1, i+1); // и заполняем его
  }
  concat(mainArr, newArr); // добавляем в основной массив
  console.log(mainArr); // смотрим, как заполняется основной массив
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Добавить элементы в массив</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для добавления элементов в начало можно воспользоваться методом [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), для обрезания массива до определенной длинны достаточно установить свойство [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length);

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

var other = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

arr.unshift(...other);
arr.length = 10;
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто скопируйте элементы в цикле. Псевдокод, учитывающий ограничение длины приёмника, чтобы не допустить переполнения:

```
start = 0; 
......//данные пришли
maxlen = 10;
for (i = 0; i <  min(maxlen - start, newData.length); i++) {
    teamsArray[start++] = newData[i];
}
```

`start` должно сохраняться до прихода следующих данных (глобальная переменная или что там у вас есть в JS)

Comment: а если так



Один массив состоит из 10 пустых элементов, он предзаполнен фейковымиданными,второй максимум из 60 элементов. Пока есть места в первом массиве мы заполняем (перезаписываем)его пришедшими элементами из второго массива. Как места закончились, мы добавляем элементы в первых массив до 62.

Comment: Это уже другая задача. Откуда вообще идея про фейковые или пустые данные? Это требуется по условию?

Comment: ну мне нужно рендерить сначала 10 штук фейковых картинок (карточек). как только приходят новые данные, они заменяются на карточки с данными.

Comment: Ну тогда сначала заменяем присваиванием, как я написал, потом добавляем новые элементы push